# Paste information in different sheets (would like to specify started at cell A1 in each sheet)

Tags: excel, vba, copy

There are 3 groups (A,B,C) of data in excel sheet1, and in my workbook i already create 3 sheets named (A, B, C).

I have no problem to copy group A,B,C data into their corresponding sheet, e.g. copy group A data into sheet A, however i find in some cases the selected cell at the beginning of each sheet is not in A1, e.g. the selected cell at the beginning maybe at somewhere other cells in excel (e.g. B10), this make the presentation looks messy, i want the all the data in each sheet start at A1.  I know some of you may said using the code Range("a1").selected can manage this situation, however we need to use the "Do loop" to loop over each row in sheet1 to identify that row is belong to A,B or C, then we paste that row into the corresponding sheet. I found if i include the code Range("a1").selected, then each time the program will paste the row in Sheet1 into the cell A1 in sheet A,B and C, and at the end there will only one row appear in each sheets.  What should i improve the program below so that each time the data in each group can be appeared at the beginning of cell A1 in their worksheet even sometimes the selected cell of each sheet is not in cell A1?  Thanks.

```vb
Sub data_category()
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim x As String
    
    Sheets("sheet1").Activate
    Range("a3").Select
    
    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
        
        y = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
        
        If y < 90 Then
            x = "A"
        ElseIf y < 120 Then
            x = "B"
        Else
            x = "C"
        End If
            
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = x
        Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlToRight)).Copy
        
        Sheets(x).Activate
        Range("a1").Select
        
        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        
        Sheets("sheet1").Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Work with objects. You may want to see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: `a3` in your code would suggest that you have headers in row `2` maybe a title in row `1` of `Sheet1`. Don't you also (want to) have headers in `A`, `B`, and `C`? Sharing the screenshots of the worksheets would clarify this or just do it verbally. Also, when you run the code once it will copy the data, but when you run it again, it will double-up the data i.e. don't you first want to clear the previous data from `A`, `B`, and `C`? Please do clarfy.

Comment: Thanks for the help from Mr. Siddharth Rout  and Tim Williams, I am now studying your program.  At the moment i had tried Mr. Siddharth one, and it works for me, but still at a prelimin. stage, i think i need some time to try and digest both programs...will provide response eventually and thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than the **Do-Loop** approach, I would do this slightly different for a **faster execution**.

**Logic**

1. Find last row in `Sheet1` of Col `A`
2. Insert formula `=IF(D3<90,"A",IF(D3<120,"B","C"))` in Col `E` starting at row `3`
3. Next I will use autofilter to filter column `E` on `A` first and copy all data in one go to Sheet `A`. I will repeat the process for `B` and `C`

**My Assumptions**

1. Row 2 has headers. If not, tweak the code accordingly.

**Code**

I have commented the code so you will not have a problem understanding it, but if you do, then simply ask.

```
Option Explicit

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Sub Sample()
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim lRow As Long
    
    With ws
        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        
        '~~> Find last row
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        '~~> Insert formula in Col E
        With .Range("E3:E" & lRow)
            .Formula = "=IF(D3<90,""A"",IF(D3<120,""B"",""C""))"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
        
        '~~> Identify the range to work with
        Set rng = .Range("A2:E" & lRow)
        
        '~~> Copy rows with relevant criteria
        CopyData "A"
        CopyData "B"
        CopyData "C"
        
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub CopyData(shName As String)
    Dim rngToCopy As Range
    
    '~~> Filter column E on the search string
    With rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=shName
        Set rngToCopy = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
    End With
    
    '~~> Copy all data in one go
    If Not rngToCopy Is Nothing Then rngToCopy.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shName).Rows(1)
    
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

**In Action**

[image]

Comment: Many thanks and your program works.  But can you tell what is wrong and how i should correct in my original codes?  Thanks.

Comment: If you want to go ahead with your original code then see Tim's code. He has shown you how it can be done.

Comment: I have just gone through your program and thanks for you taking the time to fix my problem.  By the way, I have tried to omit the code lines: "With .Range("E3:E" & lRow).value=.value" and "ws.autofiltermode=false (you use this code lines three times in the program, and i delete the second (middle) one)", it also works.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Following from Sid's comment:

```vb
Sub data_category()
    Dim y As Long
    Dim x As String, c As Range, ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, cDest As Range
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'or ThisWorkbook: always good to be specific here
    Set c = wb.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a3") 'get a reference to the starting cell
    Do Until Len(c.Value) = 0
        
        y = c.Offset(0, 3).Value
        Select Case y               'tidier then if...else if
            Case Is < 90: x = "A"
            Case Is < 120: x = "B"
            Case Else: x = "C"
        End Select
        
        c.Offset(0, 4).Value = x

        'direct copy to next empty row with no select/activate
        Set cDest = wb.Worksheets(x).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
        If Len(cDest).Value > 0 Then Set cDest = cDest.Offset(1, 0)
        c.EntireRow.Copy cDest
    
        Set c = c.Offset(1,0) '<<<<<<<<<<<<< edit - added
    Loop
    c.Parent.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim.  I have tried your solution and yes, using your codes can successfully fulfill all  the requirements.  I check the main code lines difference between you and me is "c.entirerow.copy" one, one this code line can replace my several code lines.  Thanks.  By the way, i think there are necessary to add two code lines at the end of the loop: ws.("sheet1").activate; activecell.offset(1,0).select   Thanks.

Comment: I added the sheet activate, but there's no `ActiveCell` in this approach (you can add a line to select whichever range you want)

Comment: Sorry, the added code line should be within the loop and just before the end of the loop.  Previously I entirely copy your  program and run, and found it run endlessly unless i add the two code lines ws.("sheet1").activate; activecell.offset(1,0).select.  Then it runs completely correct and no problem at all.

Comment: Sorry I skipped the `Set c = c.Offset(1,0)` line - see edit above. My bad.

Comment: Excuse me, each time the data start to populate at row 2 in each worksheets(x), what code would be if i would like to start to populate at row 1?  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to solve my problem and yes it works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### Update Category Reports

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateCategoryReports()
    
    Const sfRow As Long = 3 ' First Row (headers are in row 'sfRow - 1')
    Const sfCol As Long = 1
    
    Const dfRow As Long = 2 ' First Row (headers are in row 'dfRow - 1')
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If slRow < sfRow Then Exit Sub ' no data (highly unlikely)
    
    Dim slCol As Long
    slCol = sws.Cells(sfRow - 1, sws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet ' Destination Worksheet
    Dim durg As Range ' Destination 'UsedRange'
    Dim dcrg As Range ' Destination Clear Range
    
    ' Clear destination data.
    For Each dws In wb.Worksheets(Array("A", "B", "C"))
        Set durg = dws.UsedRange  ' Destination Used Range
        If durg.Rows.Count > 1 Then
            ' You don't want to clear the headers:
            ' e.g. if 'durg' is 'A1:J10' then 'dcrg' will be 'A2:J10'.
            Set dcrg = durg.Resize(durg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
            dcrg.Clear
        End If
    Next dws
    
    Dim srrg As Range ' Source Row Range
    Dim sRow As Long ' Source Row
    
    Dim dfCell As Range ' Destination First Cell (Range)
    Dim dRow As Long ' Destination (Available) Row
    Dim sValue As Double ' Source Value
    Dim dwsName As String ' Destination Worksheet Name
    
    For sRow = sfRow To slRow
        
        If IsNumeric(sws.Cells(sRow, "D").Value) Then
            
            sValue = sws.Cells(sRow, "D").Value
            
            If sValue < 90 Then
                dwsName = "A"
            ElseIf sValue < 120 Then
                dwsName = "B"
            Else
                dwsName = "C"
            End If
            
            Set srrg = sws.Range(sws.Cells(sRow, "A"), sws.Cells(sRow, slCol))
            sws.Cells(sRow, "E").Value = dwsName ' ?
            
            Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dwsName)
            dRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Set dfCell = dws.Cells(dRow, "A")
            
            ' This will copy values, formats, and formulas. You may need another
            ' way. If there are formulas in source and you only need values,
            ' copying by assignment is the most efficient way. If you also need
            ' the formats you will have to use the least efficient PasteSpecial.
            srrg.Copy Destination:=dfCell
        
        'Else ' sValue is not numeric: do nothing
        End If
        
    Next sRow
 
    'sws.Activate
    'sws.Cells(1).Activate

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Category reports updated.", vbInformation, "Category Reports"

End Sub
```

Comment: Many Thanks for your help.  I am a new guy in programming and it certainly will take me some time to digest your program, will get back to you once i had gone through it.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry to response so late.  Your program is very comprehensive, thanks very much.  There are some sophisticated codes in your program such as worksheets(array("A", "B", "C")) ,set = .resize.()..that i seldom encounter, I still need some time to learn each your code deeply.  I have completely put your program into my excel to run, and it runs fantastic well.  Again, Thanks for your time to help me solve my question.